# Multiple configuration in Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

Is that any chance to implement multiple configuration files in Zend Framework beside sub classing `Zend_App` class and rewrite it `_loadConfig` method to accommodate multiple file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just in bootstrap read config file first with configuation on config files to read ....

Comment: I'm very sorry, but I have to set -1 as this response is completely incomprehensible. Could you rewrite it, please, to "proper english"?